# Multiple linear regressions in a single plot

Tags: r, linear-regression, linear-algebra, lm

Sorry in advance is there is something wrong or confusing, I'm just a biologist with some basic R.

First of all I'll give some insight in the idea behind the script. I did some experiments where flies were exposed to different ramps of increasing temperatures, using a self-built device for this purpose. Having the need to know if the device increases the temperature correctly, I had to make calibration curves for every ramp. Calibration curves were measured over time with a temperature sensor.

`dput` of my first df `datos` (data in spanish) that is a resume of the temperature measured for 3 different ramps (0,06 °C/min, 0,12 °C/min, 0,25°C/min)

```
structure(list(date2 = c("03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", 
"03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", 
"03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", 
"03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", 
"03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", 
"03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/02/2021", 
"03/02/2021", "03/02/2021"), time2 = c("14:56:32", "14:56:42", 
"14:56:52", "14:57:02", "14:57:12", "14:57:22", "14:57:32", "14:57:42", 
"14:57:52", "14:58:02", "14:58:12", "14:58:22", "14:58:32", "14:58:42", 
"14:58:52", "14:59:02", "14:59:12", "14:59:22", "14:59:32", "14:59:42", 
"14:59:52", "15:00:02", "15:00:12", "15:00:22", "15:00:32", "15:00:42", 
"15:00:52", "15:01:02", "15:01:12", "15:01:22"), temperature = c(25.2, 
25.8, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.7, 25.5, 25.6, 25.5, 
25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 
25.6, 25.6, 25.8, 25.8, 25.8, 25.8, 25.8), grupo = c("voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft"), segundos = c(1L, 
11L, 21L, 31L, 41L, 51L, 61L, 71L, 81L, 91L, 101L, 111L, 121L, 
131L, 141L, 151L, 161L, 171L, 181L, 191L, 201L, 211L, 221L, 231L, 
241L, 251L, 261L, 271L, 281L, 291L), id3 = 1:30, curva = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), class = "factor"), 
    modo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "h", class = "factor"), sujeto = c("agus", 
    "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", 
    "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", 
    "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", 
    "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus"), tamb = c(26.7, 26.7, 
    26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 
    26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 
    26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7), tratamiento = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0.06", 
    "0.125", "0.25"), class = "factor"), datetime = structure(c(1612364192, 
    1612364202, 1612364212, 1612364222, 1612364232, 1612364242, 
    1612364252, 1612364262, 1612364272, 1612364282, 1612364292, 
    1612364302, 1612364312, 1612364322, 1612364332, 1612364342, 
    1612364352, 1612364362, 1612364372, 1612364382, 1612364392, 
    1612364402, 1612364412, 1612364422, 1612364432, 1612364442, 
    1612364452, 1612364462, 1612364472, 1612364482), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

`dput` of a df `datos2` that is the same resume of calibration curves, but filtered for well measured curves (those with the smallest possible variation).

```
structure(list(date2 = c("01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", 
"01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", 
"01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", 
"01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", 
"01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", 
"01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", "01/03/2021", 
"01/03/2021", "01/03/2021"), time2 = c("10:24:28", "10:24:38", 
"10:24:48", "10:24:58", "10:25:08", "10:25:18", "10:25:28", "10:25:38", 
"10:25:48", "10:25:58", "10:26:08", "10:26:18", "10:26:28", "10:26:38", 
"10:26:48", "10:26:58", "10:27:08", "10:27:18", "10:27:28", "10:27:38", 
"10:27:48", "10:27:58", "10:28:08", "10:28:18", "10:28:28", "10:28:38", 
"10:28:48", "10:28:58", "10:29:08", "10:29:18"), temperature = c(26.2, 
26.8, 26.6, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.8, 26.8, 26.8, 26.9, 26.8, 
26.8, 26.7, 26.6, 26.6, 26.7, 26.6, 26.7, 26.7, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 
26.7, 26.6, 26.9, 26.8, 26.8, 26.8, 26.8), grupo = c("voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", 
"voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft", "voltcraft"), segundos = c(1L, 
11L, 21L, 31L, 41L, 51L, 61L, 71L, 81L, 91L, 101L, 111L, 121L, 
131L, 141L, 151L, 161L, 171L, 181L, 191L, 201L, 211L, 221L, 231L, 
241L, 251L, 261L, 271L, 281L, 291L), id3 = 5315:5344, curva = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), class = "factor"), 
    modo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "h", class = "factor"), sujeto = c("agus", 
    "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", 
    "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", 
    "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", 
    "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus", "agus"), tamb = c(28, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28), tratamiento = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0.06", 
    "0.125", "0.25"), class = "factor"), datetime = structure(c(1614594268, 
    1614594278, 1614594288, 1614594298, 1614594308, 1614594318, 
    1614594328, 1614594338, 1614594348, 1614594358, 1614594368, 
    1614594378, 1614594388, 1614594398, 1614594408, 1614594418, 
    1614594428, 1614594438, 1614594448, 1614594458, 1614594468, 
    1614594478, 1614594488, 1614594498, 1614594508, 1614594518, 
    1614594528, 1614594538, 1614594548, 1614594558), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Essentially is the same df just filtered as it follows

```
datos2=datos %>% filter((tratamiento == "0.125" & segundos < 4001 & (curva == 
"a" | curva == "b"|curva == "c" | curva == "d" | curva == "f")) | (tratamiento 
== "0.25" & segundos < 4001 & (curva == "a" | curva == "e" | curva == "j")) | 
(tratamiento == "0.06" & segundos < 4001 & (curva == "d" | curva == "e"| curva == "f")) )
```

Plot of `datos2` for 3 different ramps (this will be needed as an idea for the final plot)

[image]

Next I used a linear model (tested the assumptions as well) so I could get the real coefficients and with that the "real" slope of each curve that relates to the real increasing temperature. For this chunk I used

`modelo <- lm(datos2$temperature~datos2$segundos*datos2$tratamiento)`

Coefficients obtained by linear model (slope in minutes):

```
> data.frame(modelo$coefficients)
                                        modelo.coefficients
(Intercept)                                   26.3091784959
datos2$segundos                                0.0006260104
datos2$tratamiento0.125                       -1.0105069266
datos2$tratamiento0.25                        -1.2511820668
datos2$segundos:datos2$tratamiento0.125        0.0015812593
datos2$segundos:datos2$tratamiento0.25         0.0047528818
```

```
#0.06
modelo$coefficients[1]=25 #intercept
round(modelo$coefficients[2]*60,3) #slope 

#0.125
modelo$coefficients[1]+modelo$coefficients[3]
round((modelo$coefficients[2]+modelo$coefficients[5])*60,3)

#0.25
modelo$coefficients[1]+modelo$coefficients[4]
round((modelo$coefficients[2]+modelo$coefficients[6])*60,3)
```

Summed up

```
0.06 <- 0.038
0.125 <- 0.132
0.25 <- 0.323
```

Finally, I tried to merge all of this in a single plot. For this I generated a predicted ramp using the estimated ramp equation for each treatment (each curve). I used a small vector for this (10800 as last number so all curves intersect X at the same time). And last I applied predict as a function to apply estimated equation to calculate Y that should be expected. This is where I get all kind of errors that I dont understand and couldnt resolve.

```
new_datos <- data.frame(segundos = rep(seq(0,10800,length.out=100),3),tratamiento = c(rep("0.06",200),rep("0.125",200),rep("0.25",200)))
```

`dput` of  `new_datos`

```
structure(list(segundos = c(0, 109.090909090909, 218.181818181818, 
327.272727272727, 436.363636363636, 545.454545454545, 654.545454545455, 
763.636363636364, 872.727272727273, 981.818181818182, 1090.90909090909, 
1200, 1309.09090909091, 1418.18181818182, 1527.27272727273, 1636.36363636364, 
1745.45454545455, 1854.54545454545, 1963.63636363636, 2072.72727272727, 
2181.81818181818, 2290.90909090909, 2400, 2509.09090909091, 2618.18181818182, 
2727.27272727273, 2836.36363636364, 2945.45454545455, 3054.54545454545, 
3163.63636363636), tratamiento = c("0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", 
"0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", 
"0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", 
"0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", "0.06", 
"0.06", "0.06")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Rest of the script for linear model:

```
b <- data.frame(predict.lm(modelo,data=new_datos,interval = "prediction"))


nrow(b)
new_datos$temperature <- b[,1]
new_datos$lwr <- b[,2]
new_datos$upr <- b[,3]
new_datos[new_datos$segundos==0]
levels(new_datos$tratamiento)[levels(datos$tratamiento)=="0.06"] <- "0.038 ºC/min"
levels(new_datos$tratamiento)[levels(datos$tratamiento)=="0.125"] <- "0.132 ºC/min"
levels(new_datos$tratamiento)[levels(datos$tratamiento)=="0.25"] <- "0.323 ºC/min"

# Split datos into Training and Testing
sample_size = floor(0.2*nrow(datos2))
# randomly split datos 
picked = sample(seq_len(nrow(datos2)),size = sample_size)
development =datos2[picked,]
```

And errors for this last part

```
> b <- data.frame(predict.lm(modelo,data=new_datos,interval = "prediction"))
Warning message:
In predict.lm(modelo, data = new_datos, interval = "prediction") :
  predictions on current data refer to _future_ responses

> new_datos$temperature <- b[,1]
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, temperature, value = c(25.0006260103883,  : 
  replacement has 7452 rows, data has 600
> new_datos$lwr <- b[,2]
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, lwr, value = c(22.6325633882165, 22.638854566693,  : 
  replacement has 7452 rows, data has 600
> levels(new_datos$tratamiento)[levels(datos$tratamiento)=="0.06"] <- "0.038 ºC/min"
Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("0.038 ºC/min", NA, NA)) : 
  factor level [3] is duplicated
> levels(new_datos$tratamiento)[levels(datos$tratamiento)=="0.125"] <- "0.132 ºC/min"
Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(NA, "0.132 ºC/min", NA)) : 
  factor level [3] is duplicated
```

Question is: Is there a way to get every curve (might be in grey in the back) in the Sup.3. in a single plot and in addition 3 curves for every coefficient (slope) calculated superimposed over the curves (in grey in the back)?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Minimum reproducible example:

```
    temperature segundos curva tratamiento
1          25.2        1     a        0.06
2          25.8       11     a        0.06
3          25.6       21     a        0.06
4          25.6       31     a        0.06
5          25.6       41     a        0.06
6          25.6       51     a        0.06
7          25.6       61     a        0.06
8          25.6       71     a        0.06
9          25.7       81     a        0.06
10         25.5       91     a        0.06
11         25.6      101     a        0.06
12         25.5      111     a        0.06
13         25.6      121     a        0.06
14         25.6      131     a        0.06
15         25.6      141     a        0.06
16         25.6      151     a        0.06
17         25.6      161     a        0.06
18         25.6      171     a        0.06
19         25.6      181     a        0.06
20         25.6      191     a        0.06
21         25.6      201     a        0.06
22         25.6      211     a        0.06
23         25.6      221     a        0.06
24         25.6      231     a        0.06
25         25.6      241     a        0.06
26         25.8      251     a        0.06
27         25.8      261     a        0.06
28         25.8      271     a        0.06
29         25.8      281     a        0.06
30         25.8      291     a        0.06
31         25.7      301     a        0.06
32         25.8      311     a        0.06
33         25.7      321     a        0.06
34         25.7      331     a        0.06
35         25.8      341     a        0.06
36         25.8      351     a        0.06
37         25.7      361     a        0.06
38         25.7      371     a        0.06
39         25.7      381     a        0.06
40         25.9      391     a        0.06
41         25.9      401     a        0.06
42         25.9      411     a        0.06
43         25.9      421     a        0.06
44         25.9      431     a        0.06
45         25.9      441     a        0.06
46         25.9      451     a        0.06
47         25.9      461     a        0.06
48         25.9      471     a        0.06
49         25.9      481     a        0.06
50         25.9      491     a        0.06
51         25.9      501     a        0.06
52         25.9      511     a        0.06
53         25.9      521     a        0.06
54         25.9      531     a        0.06
55         25.9      541     a        0.06
56         25.9      551     a        0.06
57         25.9      561     a        0.06
58         25.9      571     a        0.06
59         25.9      581     a        0.06
60         25.9      591     a        0.06
61         25.8      601     a        0.06
62         25.9      611     a        0.06
63         26.0      621     a        0.06
64         25.9      631     a        0.06
65         26.2      641     a        0.06
66         26.1      651     a        0.06
67         26.1      661     a        0.06
68         26.1      671     a        0.06
69         26.1      681     a        0.06
70         26.1      691     a        0.06
71         26.1      701     a        0.06
72         26.1      711     a        0.06
73         26.2      721     a        0.06
74         26.1      731     a        0.06
75         26.1      741     a        0.06
76         26.1      751     a        0.06
77         26.1      761     a        0.06
78         26.1      771     a        0.06
79         26.2      781     a        0.06
80         26.3      791     a        0.06
81         26.1      801     a        0.06
82         26.3      811     a        0.06
83         26.1      821     a        0.06
84         26.3      831     a        0.06
85         26.1      841     a        0.06
86         26.3      851     a        0.06
87         26.4      861     a        0.06
88         26.3      871     a        0.06
89         26.3      881     a        0.06
90         26.3      891     a        0.06
91         26.3      901     a        0.06
92         26.3      911     a        0.06
93         26.3      921     a        0.06
94         26.3      931     a        0.06
95         26.3      941     a        0.06
96         26.2      951     a        0.06
97         26.3      961     a        0.06
98         26.3      971     a        0.06
99         26.3      981     a        0.06
100        26.3      991     a        0.06
101        26.5     1001     a        0.06
102        26.3     1011     a        0.06
103        26.5     1021     a        0.06
104        26.5     1031     a        0.06
105        26.5     1041     a        0.06
106        26.5     1051     a        0.06
107        26.5     1061     a        0.06
108        26.5     1071     a        0.06
109        26.6     1081     a        0.06
110        26.5     1091     a        0.06
111        26.5     1101     a        0.06
112        26.5     1111     a        0.06
113        26.6     1121     a        0.06
114        26.5     1131     a        0.06
115        26.5     1141     a        0.06
116        26.5     1151     a        0.06
117        26.5     1161     a        0.06
118        26.5     1171     a        0.06
119        26.6     1181     a        0.06
120        26.5     1191     a        0.06
121        26.5     1201     a        0.06
122        26.5     1211     a        0.06
123        26.5     1221     a        0.06
124        26.6     1231     a        0.06
125        26.5     1241     a        0.06
126        26.6     1251     a        0.06
127        26.7     1261     a        0.06
128        26.7     1271     a        0.06
129        26.8     1281     a        0.06
130        26.5     1291     a        0.06
131        26.7     1301     a        0.06
132        26.7     1311     a        0.06
133        26.7     1321     a        0.06
134        26.8     1331     a        0.06
135        26.7     1341     a        0.06
136        26.5     1351     a        0.06
137        26.7     1361     a        0.06
138        26.7     1371     a        0.06
139        26.8     1381     a        0.06
140        26.7     1391     a        0.06
141        26.8     1401     a        0.06
142        26.7     1411     a        0.06
143        26.8     1421     a        0.06
144        26.8     1431     a        0.06
145        26.7     1441     a        0.06
146        26.7     1451     a        0.06
147        26.8     1461     a        0.06
148        26.8     1471     a        0.06
149        26.7     1481     a        0.06
150        26.8     1491     a        0.06
151        26.7     1501     a        0.06
152        26.7     1511     a        0.06
153        26.7     1521     a        0.06
154        26.7     1531     a        0.06
155        26.8     1541     a        0.06
156        26.8     1551     a        0.06
157        26.7     1561     a        0.06
158        26.8     1571     a        0.06
159        26.7     1581     a        0.06
160        26.8     1591     a        0.06
161        27.0     1601     a        0.06
162        27.0     1611     a        0.06
163        27.0     1621     a        0.06
164        27.0     1631     a        0.06
165        27.0     1641     a        0.06
166        27.0     1651     a        0.06
167        27.0     1661     a        0.06
168        27.0     1671     a        0.06
169        27.0     1681     a        0.06
170        27.0     1691     a        0.06
171        27.0     1701     a        0.06
172        27.0     1711     a        0.06
173        27.0     1721     a        0.06
174        27.0     1731     a        0.06
175        27.0     1741     a        0.06
176        26.9     1751     a        0.06
177        27.0     1761     a        0.06
178        27.0     1771     a        0.06
179        27.0     1781     a        0.06
180        27.0     1791     a        0.06
181        27.0     1801     a        0.06
182        27.0     1811     a        0.06
183        27.3     1821     a        0.06
184        27.2     1831     a        0.06
185        27.2     1841     a        0.06
186        27.2     1851     a        0.06
187        27.2     1861     a        0.06
188        27.3     1871     a        0.06
189        27.2     1881     a        0.06
190        27.2     1891     a        0.06
191        27.2     1901     a        0.06
192        27.2     1911     a        0.06
193        27.2     1921     a        0.06
194        27.2     1931     a        0.06
195        27.2     1941     a        0.06
196        27.4     1951     a        0.06
197        27.4     1961     a        0.06
198        27.5     1971     a        0.06
199        27.4     1981     a        0.06
200        27.3     1991     a        0.06
```

Sketch:

[image]

This is an idea, but with the 3 treatments in a single plot (as in next image)

[image]

The idea is to plot adjusted curves of estimated ramps (in any combination of colors) and real curves obtained too (in grey so the slope of the curves is "highlighted")

**EDIT2:**
Plot with suggestions provided:

[image]

Yet this is without training and testing data, thus it is not the 'real' slopes measured. When I try to make a plot using `b`:

```r
#solved errors making a bigger vector to fit my data
new_datos <- data.frame(segundos = rep(seq(0,5000,length.out=2484),1),tratamiento = c(rep("0.06",2484),rep("0.125",2484),rep("0.25",2484)))
```

Since I've never provided proper way on how I'm trying to plot:

```r
ggplot(new_datos,aes(x=segundos,y=temperature,group = tratamiento,colour=tratamiento)) +
   geom_point(data=development,aes(x=segundos,y=temperature,group = curva),size = 1,alpha=0.8,color="grey50",show.legend = FALSE) +
   geom_point(size = 3,show.legend = FALSE) + labs(x="Tiempo (s)", y="Temperatura (ºC)") +
   geom_text(aes(x = segundos, y = temperature+1, label = c("0,038 °C/min", "0.132 ºC/min","0.323 ºC/min")),color = "black",data = new_datos[c(200,250,500),]) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("#3B9AB2", "#E8C520", "#F21A00","grey"))
```

Then script is the same as before.
Final plot:
[image]

Comment: You've explained your problem pretty clearly and provided the code you're running. Well done! Unfortunately, it seems like the first `dput` you've provided for `datos` is only the first five lines of your data frame, which means that I can't run any of your code. Are you able to provide a minimum reproducible example, by removing any unnecessary code but including all the needed data? This doesn't haven't to be your hard-earned, real data. Can you come up with some example data (e.g., random numbers) and then ask your plotting question based on that?

Comment: Alternatively, can you give us a drawing (even a hand drawn sketch that you photograph and upload) that shows what graph you're trying to produce? Maybe we can work backwards from there.

Comment: Also, a hint: `curva == 
"a" | curva == "b" | curva == "c" | curva == "d" | curva == "f"` can be replaced with `curva %in% c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f')` to reduce the length of your code (and therefore make it easier to read).

Comment: @StewartMacdonald Thank you for taking the time in answering!

I've already edited the `dput` for `datos`, but I edited it too with an example without all unnecessary columns. I've also provided an example of the final plot I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm generating some test data and using that to demonstrate how to achieve what I think you're asking, because the data you've supplied is still not complete enough to run your code (which isn't a big problem - I think this sample data illustrates the concepts well enough):

```
# How many 'curves' and 'treatments' do we want?
n_curve <- 6
n_treat <- 3
n <- n_curve * n_treat

# Take the cars dataset and repeat it n times
dataDF <- do.call("rbind", replicate(n, cars, simplify = FALSE))

# Assign a curve ID
dataDF$curve <- as.factor(rep(letters[1:n_curve], each=nrow(cars)))

# Assign a treatment ID
dataDF$treatment <- as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:n_treat], each=nrow(cars)))

# Adjust the data by a small, random number so that our curves aren't identical
dataDF$speed2 <- dataDF$speed + dataDF$speed * (sample(c(-6:6), size=nrow(dataDF), replace=T) / 100)
dataDF$dist2  <- dataDF$dist +   dataDF$dist * (sample(c(-6:6), size=nrow(dataDF), replace=T) / 100)
head(dataDF)

# Make sure that data differ between treatments
dataDF$dist2  <- dataDF$dist2  * (as.numeric(dataDF$treatment)^2)

# The 'real' data are plotted in grey
# I'm using geom_smooth() to build a linear model of the data and
# then plotting that in red. You can instead build a separate lm
# and use the predict() function to generate new data, and then
# plot that here by adding another line along the lines of:
#  geom_line(data=new_datos, aes(x=segundos, y=temperature))
ggplot(dataDF, aes(x=speed2, y=dist2)) +
  geom_line(col='grey50') +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', col='red', fill='red') +
  facet_grid(cols=vars(treatment))
```

This gives us one plot with separate subplots ('facets') for each treatment. The original curves, based on real data, are drawn in grey. The line from the linear model (here, generated by `geom_smooth()` inside the ggplot block) is plotted on top in red.

[image]

You can also do this on one plot and colour the curve lines so that they're not all grey:

```
# We can also do this in one plot by removing the facet
# and colouring the geom_smooth() lines by treatment:
ggplot(dataDF, aes(x=speed2, y=dist2, col=treatment, fill=treatment)) +
  geom_line(alpha=0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what you're aiming for, but hopefully that gives you something to start with. Feel free to leave a comment on this answer if you need additional info.

Comment: Hi there! You've explained it very clear, and could get some ideas out of your example to make a better plot. 

Yet is not the final plot. In the last part of my script (before my first edit) I've managed to solve the error, yet I get a horrible plot. This is because `b` is using `modelo` as a variable and in addition `modelo` is using each curve as a variable. Because of this, there is one slope for each curve (1 curve=1 measurement - replica). I hope I made my self clear, in any case feel free to ask. I will edit my question with this info.

Comment: Managed to get a plot! Thanks for the help!